# Can't load form to create new instance of model

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-cli, mvp

**router.js** has

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('concepts');
  this.route('create-concept', { path: '/concepts/new' });
  this.route('concept', { path: '/concepts/:id' });
});
```

**controllers/create-concept.js** has

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var concept = this.store.createRecord('concept', {
        description: this.get('description').trim()
      });
      this.set('description', '');
      concept.save();
    }
  }
});
```

**templates/create-concept.js** has

```
{{textarea value="description"}}

{{action 'create'}}
```

**routes/create-concept.js** is just the default

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

When I go to the URL `/concepts/new` in my browser, however, I just get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

in my browser. I have no idea what the cause of this generic error would be, and documentation on this seems to be pretty sparse...

**EDIT** -- when I am visiting /concepts and click on a link to /concepts/new, it shows

```
Preparing to transition from 'concepts' to ' create-concept'
Transitioned into 'create-concept'
```

so it would appear that it does find the correct route

Since it's hard to copy and paste this for some reason, here's a screenshot of part of the stack trace:

**EDIT 2** -- **[Minimal code demonstrating problem](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bibecewali/1/edit?html,js,output)**

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Will you include the stack trace, tossing in the info I added as an answer below was just a portion, and doesn't answer your first problem.

Comment: Also, I think you've got a potentially clashing route, although Ember might be fine with it, I'm not positive, it could always see `/concepts/new` as the `concept` route with the id being `new`

Comment: I'd probably simplify, comment out as much as possible, if you want to try and duplicate on emberjs.jsbin.com, that will also help.

Comment: @Kingpin2k updated minimal code -- only a few lines cause this problem. I must be misunderstanding something with Ember

Comment: Updated, I don't know why I didn't see it before in your question, something about seeing it in code opens up my eyes.  the action helper needs to be applied to an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really want `value="description"`, you probably mean `value=description`

One assigns the literal string `description` to the value property, the other binds the property `description` to the value property.

Your action needs to actually be attached to something!  A div, button, anchor tag.

```
<div {{action 'create'}}>blah</div>

<button {{action 'create'}}>blah</button>
```

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/

Comment: Oh! Hahaha should've looked more closely at the example, thanks so much :)